# Can we get the ability to search for “user:current”?

Tags: feature-request, search, current-user

On some pages, you can put “current” where the user ID would go and it will redirect to the logged-in user’s version of the page; for example, `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current` would redirect to `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/edit/102999` for me.

It’d be nice to extend this feature to search; user IDs are long and hard to memorize, so what if we could type `user:current` in search to find posts by ourselves?

Comment: You can already do this with `user:me` or `user:mine`.

Comment: @animuson oh :P. I didn’t know that—I’ll leave this up because this’d be nice to have for consistency with the URLs